# OPENCV CUDA -- getCudaEnabledDeviceCount return 0

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, image-stitching

I am a fresh to opencv with cuda.
I use opencv2.4.6 and CUDA4.2.
I have successfuly compile the opencv with cuda.
when i use the code:

```
int cuda_count;
cudaError_t error = cudaGetDeviceCount( &cuda_count );
```

it returns `cudaSuccess` and `cuda_count=1`
But, when i use the code:

```
int num_devices = cv::gpu::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount();
```

the `num_devices returns 0`
why?

my complete code is:

```
int main()
{

int num_devices = cv::gpu::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount();

    int cuda_count;
    cudaError_t error = cudaGetDeviceCount( &cuda_count );

    if(num_devices <=0 )
    {
        std::cerr << "no" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int enable_devivce_id = -1;
}
```

Comment: but when I debug the example "opencv_test_gpu" the cv::gpu::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount() returns 1; I really confused. thinks!

Answer (score 1):

you must have been compiled OpenCV without CUDA support

> gpu::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount Returns the number of installed
>   CUDA-enabled devices.
>
> C++: int gpu::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()
>
> Use this function before any
>   other GPU functions calls. If OpenCV is compiled without GPU support,
>   this function returns 0.